# a tabela não receber cadastro

Tags: php, mysql, bdd

Boa Tarde amigos, estou fazendo tentando fazer um Código php que envolver Banco de dados, e no decorrer do codigo me deparei com um erro a qual não consigo resolver. 
ao tenta cadastrar um dado pela web, ele não cadastrar de maneira nenhuma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui],
 ja quando tento pelo promt de comados o cadastro da sucesso

abaixo segue os codigos que estou usando.

**index.php**

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==0 and isset($_SESSION['nome'])==0){
  echo "<script> window.location='login.php'</script>";
}else{
  $id=$_SESSION['id'];
  $nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
  echo "<h3>usuario: $nome <a href='login.php'>sair</a></h3>";
}
?>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <TITLE>Cadastros</TITLE>
 <style>
 h1{
    color:#8080FF;
    background-color:#FF6A6A;
    margin-top:-7;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 3px #800080;
    padding:25px;
    font-size:60px;
    margin-left:-8;
    margin-right:-1;
    }
    input[type=submit],input[type=text]{
    background-color:#FF6A6A ;
    border:2px solid #800080;
    border-radius:9px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    fieldset{
    margin-top:-40;
    background-color:#FFFFC0;
     margin-left:-8;
    margin-right:-1;
    }body{
    background-color:#8080FF;
    }#p1{
    color:green;
    }#p2{
    color:red;
    }th{
    color:#800080;
    }td{
    color:#000080;
    }#p3{
    color:#FF00FF;
    }#p4{
    color:#800000;
    }  h3{
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:90;
    }
 </style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
 <h1>Cadastro de Produtos</h1>
 <fieldset>
  <BR>
  <table >
  <form action ="evento.php?cadastro=true" method = "post" >
<tr>
  <td><label>Produto:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" value='' name='produto' placeholder='Digite o nome do produto' required ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label>Preço:</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" value ='' name='preco' placeholder='Digite o preço do produto' required ></td>
</tr>
</table>
 <BR>
 <input type="submit" value="cadastrar">
 </form>
 <BR>
 <BR>
 <table border="5">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Produto</th>
  <th>Preço</th>
  <th>Funcionário</th>
  <th>Alterar</th>
  <th>Excluir</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<center>
 <?php
            include_once "conexao.php";
            $sql = "select * from produto";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            if($result){
            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tbody>
       <tr>
           <td id='p3'> <?php  echo $linha['codigo'];?></td>
           <td> <?php echo $linha['nome'];?></td>
           <td id='p4'> <?php echo $linha['preco'];?></td>
           <td> <?php echo $linha['id_funcionario'];?></td>       
           <td> <?php echo "<a id='p1' href = editar.php?editar=".$linha['codigo']." >editar </a>";?></td>
           <td> <?php echo "<a id='p2' href = evento.php?deletar=".$linha['codigo'].">excluir</a>";?></td>
       <tr>
</tbody>
<?php
          }//fim do while
          }//fim do if
          mysql_close($con);
?>
</table> 
</fieldset>
<h3 align="center">&copy Amem!</h3>
<BR>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**login.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
 h1{
    color:#8080FF;
    background-color:#FF6A6A;
    margin-top:-7;
    text-shadow:1px 2px 3px #800080;
    padding:25px;
    font-size:60px;
    margin-left:-8;
    margin-right:-1;
    }
    input[type=submit],input[type=text]{
    background-color:#FF6A6A;
    border:2px solid #800080;
    border-radius:9px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    input[type=submit],input[type=password]{
    background-color:#FF6A6A;
    border:2px solid #800080;
    border-radius:9px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    fieldset{
    margin-top:-40;
    background-color:#FFFFC0;
     margin-left:-8;
    margin-right:-1;
    }body{
    background-color:#8080FF;
    }#p1{
    color:green;
    }#p2{
    color:red;
    }th{
    color:#800080;
    }td{
    color:#000080;
    }#p3{
    color:#FF00FF;
    }#p4{
    color:#800000;
    }  h3{
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top:90;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<h1>Sistema Controle de Produtos</h1>
<fieldset>
<form method="post" action="">
 Login:
 <input type="text" name="login" required><br><br>
 Senha:
 <input type="password" name="senha" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
  </center>
</form>
</fieldset>
<h3 align="center">&copy Amem!</h3>
<?php
include_once "conexao.php";
if(isset($_POST['login']))$login = $_POST['login'];
if(isset($_POST['senha']))$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$sql="select * from funcionario where nome='$login' and senha='$senha'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$res=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($res){
 $linha=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id_funcionario'];
 $_SESSION['nome']=$linha['nome'];
 echo "<script> window.location=' index.php'</script>";  
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**conexao.php**

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>Conexao</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $login="root";
  $senha="";
  $banco="controle_de_estoque";

  $con=mysql_connect($host,$login,$senha)or die("Erro ao conecta!".mysql_error());
  $sql="create database if not exists ".$banco;
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  mysql_select_db($banco,$con);
  $sql = "create table if not exists funcionario(
  id_funcionario int(8) auto_increment,
  nome varchar(100) not null,
  senha varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(id_funcionario))";
  mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $sql="create table if not exists produto(codigo int(8) auto_increment,
  nome varchar(100) not null, preco double not null, id_funcionario int(8) not null,
  primary key(codigo), foreign key(id_funcionario) references funcionario(id_funcionario))";
  mysql_query($sql);
?>

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

**evento.php**

```html
<?php
 include_once'conexao.php';
 if(isset($_POST['produto']))$atrProduto = $_POST['produto'];
 if(isset($_POST['preco']))$atrPreco = $_POST['preco'];
 if(isset($_GET['cadastro']))
 {
 $sql = "insert into produto values(0,'".$atrProduto."','".$atrPreco."')";
 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo "<script>alert('Produto cadastrado com sucesso!')</script>";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['deletar'])){
 $sql = "delete from produto where codigo = ".$_GET['deletar'];
 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo "<script>alert('Produto deletado com sucesso!')</script>";
 }
 if(isset($_GET['editar'])){
 $sql = "update produto set nome= '".$atrProduto."',preco='".$atrPreco."' where codigo=".$_GET['editar'];
 mysql_query($sql,$con);
 echo"<script> alert('Produto atualizado com sucesso')</script>";
 }
 echo"<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";
```

**editar.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <?php
 include_once 'conexao.php';
 $sql='select * from produto where codigo='.$_GET['editar'];
 $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
 $linha=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>
 <h3> Editar Contato </h3>
 <?php echo "<form action= 'evento.php?editar=".$linha['codigo']."'method='post'>";?>
  Produto: <input type="text" name="produto" value="<?php echo $linha['nome'];?>"><p></p>
  Preço: <input type="text" name="preco" value="<?php echo $linha['preco'];?>"><p></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Editar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```html
<?php
 session_star();
 unset($_SESSION['id']);
 unset($_SESSION['nome']);
 session_destroy();
 echo "<script> window.location='login.php'</script>";
 ?>
```

.

alguém poderia me ajudar a achar meu erro, eu pensei em colocar no evento.php `$sql = "insert into produto values(0,'".$atrProduto."','".$atrPreco."',1)";` desse jeito porem ia ficar cadastrando tudo no usuário 1, e eu queria para quando eu mudasse de sessão e colocasse vamos dizer um usuário que ta no ID 2, o id na hora de cadastrar aparecesse 2 e assim sucessivamente. alguém poderia me ajudar nesse ponto tbm? realmente não tenho mais ideia do quer fazer. realmente preciso da ajuda de meus amigos. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está na linha `mysql_query($sql,$con);`

Dando uma olhada na estrutura de sua tabela, podemos ver que o campo `id_funcionario` é do tipo `not null`, portanto, você *deve* preencher um valor número.

Você pode fazer:

```
$userId = isset($_SESSION["id"]) ? $_SESSION["id"] : 1;

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `produto` SET `nome` = \"%s\", `preco` = \"%s\", `id_funcionario` = \"%d\";",
    $atrProduto,
    $atrPreco,
    $userId);
```

Caso você, ainda sim, não consiga cadastrar o produto, utilize a função `mysql_error` abaixo do `insert` para visualizar o problema.

```
die( mysql_error($link) );
```

Ps.: Só lembrando que o `mysql_` não é mais utilizado. Se possível troque para o `mysqli_`

Comment: agradeço muito pela ajuda, porem infelizmente ainda continua persistindo no mesmo erro. mas muito obrigado. vou continuar tentando resolver esse problema.

Comment: Ah e sobre o mysqli_ eu ja fiquei sabendo, porem uso dois Pc diferente quando estou programando( o da meu mesmo e o do colegio) e a versão do xampp do colegio é desatualizada ai acabar dando alguns erros ao usar o mysqli_

Comment: Adicione o `mysql_error` e posta o erro que você recebe. Verifique também se `$_SESSION["id"]` está retornando um valor numérico.

Comment: Após usar o mysql_error recebi tais erros

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabalho\evento.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabalho\evento.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Trabalho\evento.php on line 13

Comment: O primeiro erro você esqueceu de adicionar o `$`, o correto é `$_SESSION`. O segundo erro significa que o valor de `$_SESSION["id"]` é null, e ele deve ser número (como expliquei na resposta). Editei o meu código, adicionei uma verificação no `id`.

Comment: com a alteração que você fez, deu certo e ja está cadastrando. porem sempre cadastrar no Funcionário 1. e quando mudo de login e coloco um com um Id por exemplo 3. continua cadastrando como funcionário 1. existe uma maneira de sempre que mudar de usuário o Id tambem mude sem ter que ir alterar manualmente o numero 1 no codigo ?

Comment: Isso acontece pois o login não está salvando o ID do funcionário na session ou os dados de usuário e senha estão incorretos. Você pode criar uma outra pergunta com essa dúvida e podemos verificar. Não posso misturar as respostas pois é contra as regras do site.

Comment: tudo bem, eu entendo. muito obrigado pela ajuda. aprendi muito com você hoje. infelizmente tenho menos de 15 de reputação e não posso colocar 1 ponto na sua resposta. mas fico super grato pela sua ajuda